# Keyboard Click Sound?

Tags: keyboard

Is there any way to turn on a sound effect each time a key is pressed on the keyboard? I an writing long textfiles and would like to receive an audio feedback typing!

example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCKspI_zyrQ

Is there no tool to apply sfx to system events for ubuntu?

Comment: If you find a way, I'd recommend a shortcut to toggle it easily, I'd imagine it could get annoying *fast*

Comment: Get a mechanical keyboard? IBM Model 2 is particularly clicky.

Comment: When working on a notebook? Would help when working with a desktop system. thx!

Comment: If you're on 17.04 or later, you can try `sudo apt install bucklespring`, then use the `buckle` command [as seen here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366283/261076).

Answer (score 11):

[bucklespring](https://github.com/zevv/bucklespring)

Can be installed from repository with

```
sudo apt install bucklespring
```

Buckle emulates the sound of an old IBM Model-M space saver
bucklespring keyboard while typing within an X session.

It runs as a background process and plays back the sound of each key
pressed and released on the keyboard, just as if using an IBM Model-M.
The sound of each key has carefully been sampled, and is played back
while simulating the proper distance and direction for a realistic 3D
sound palette of pure nostalgic bliss.

[linux-clicky](https://github.com/skkeeper/linux-clicky)

Entirely written in Python, supports basic volume control. It's possible to diversify the sound of some keys. By default the SPACE and ENTER key have a specific sound.

Comment: Need to be run by user, not root. Start via `buckle &`. It is stereo, so left keys are on left speaker etc.

Comment: bucklespring does not seem to support the numeric keypad on my HP notebook. Some versions of the model M had a numeric keypad, such as the M13, M5-2, and M2.  To avoid error messages due to missing sound files for the numeric keypad keys run the program with the `-f` option that causes a default sound file to be used if a specific file is missing. `buckle -f &`